# How to get data to a running ruby process?

Tags: ruby, communication, environment

I have a datastore with a cache and a db, simple.  The tricksy part is that I want a way to control if the the datastore hits the db in a real-time way.  That is to say while the process is running I want to be able to toggle if it's connected to the db or not.

I looked into env variables, but it doesn't seem like those get updated as the process runs.  Is there a simple way to get a bit from the command line into the running process, or do I just need to rely on ops being able to drop the db listeners in case of disaster?

Note that this is all being done in vanilla ruby - not ruby on rails.

Thanks!
-Jess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use named pipes for simple communication:

```
#pipes.rb:
f = File.open 'mypipe', 'r+'
loop do
  begin
    s = f.read_nonblock 1
  rescue Exception
  end
  case s
  when '0'
    puts 'Turn off DB access!'
  when '1'
    puts 'Turn on DB access!'
  end
  sleep 1
end
```

And you can control your db access externally by writing to the named pipe:

```
jablan-mbp:dev $ echo 101 > mypipe
```

Which results in:

```
jablan-mbp:dev $ ruby pipes.rb 
Turn on DB access!
Turn off DB access!
Turn on DB access!
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is what we ended up doing.  I just had some vain hope that there was something simpler, but really this isn't bad.

Answer (score 0):

A shared-memory strategy might be worth considering. Assuming you're running on a POSIX system, check out [mmap](http://moulon.inra.fr/ruby/mmap.html) for memory-mapped files, and [SysVIPC](http://sysvipc.rubyforge.org/) for message queues, semaphores, and shared memory.

Comment: Yeah, I could do that - set up a command line script that'd pass the message over to the ruby process.  It's a good point.  I was hoping for a simpler solution, but everything, of course, is that underneath anyway.  Kinda a pita to implement though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *NIX, have you considered signals? (`kill -HUP pid`) - http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Signal.html